# Alamofire and PromiseKit returning a Promise<[T]>

Tags: swift, alamofire, promisekit

I used Alamofire and PromiseKit as separate Cocoapod installs. I can retrieve the JSON data using Alamofire, but I am receiving the error below when configuring PromiseKit. The error below appears in the line where 'fulfill, reject' are in.

Error message: Contextual closure type '(Resolver<_>) -> Void' expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body

I am using Xcode 9.2 and IOS 11.2 inside of the Simulator. Thank you for your advice in advance!

```
      func wantToReturnAnArrayOfActor() -> Promise<[Actor]> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        Alamofire.request(ApiUrl.url.rawValue).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch(response.result)
            {
               case .success(let responseString): print("my response string = \(responseString)")
               let actorResponse = ActorApiResponse(JSONString: "\(responseString)")//converts all of the data into the ActorApiResponse model class
              return when(fulfilled: actorResponse)
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("actorResponse = \(String(describing: actorResponse))")
                }

               case .failure(let error): print("alamofire error = \(error)")

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it rather be like this,

```
func wantToReturnAnArrayOfActor() -> Promise<[Actor]> {

    return Promise() { resolver in

        Alamofire.request(ApiUrl.url.rawValue).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch(response.result)
            {
            case .success(let responseObject):
                let actorResponse = ActorApiResponse(jsonObject: responseObject)
                let actors = actorResponse.getActors()
                resolver.fulfill(actors)

            case .failure(let error):
                resolver.reject(error)

            }
        }

    }
}
```

The initializer closure for Promise takes in single argument, which is of type *Resolver*, which is what your error says. Then, you would want to resolve your promise with result which is of type *[Actor]* when the promise execution is finished or then reject with error if error occurred during the execution.

Few points to note here:

- *Alamofire.request(_).responseJSON* returns json object not json string.
- If your *ActorApiResponse* is the object which transforms the json to [Actor], you should have proper method to convert json object to actual data type ie. [Actor].

You could have your *ActorApiResponse* something like this,

```
struct ActorApiResponse {
    init(jsonObject: Any) {

    }

    func getActors() -> [Actor] {
        // calculate and return actors
        return []
    }
}
```

Then, you can call it from else where,

```
    wantToReturnAnArrayOfActor().done {
       // do something with [Actor here]
       // You can also chain the multiple promise using .then instead of using done
        }.catch { error in
            print("Error occurred \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: Sandeep, thank you very much for your response! I am using ObjectMapper to associate the JSON data with my model. I am can see the data via the print( ), but I am recieving this error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 6." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 6.}